# if statement inside "onClick" methode

Tags: android

In my onClick method I did something like :

```
    switch(arg0.getId()){
       case R.id.b_1:
        //some code
        break;
      case R.id.b_2:
       //some code
       break;
       ...
    }
    if (num1==num2){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"WOW", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
```

but it seems that even when num1==num2 the Toast doesn't apper..
What can be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: try to log the values of num1 and num2 inside the if condition.so that,you will get to know weather control goes into if statement or just skipping it.

Comment: I reformatted your code and noticed an extra `}`. Are you sure the code isn't exiting before the `if` statement?

Comment: Try moving the if-statement up above the switch-statement - is it run then?

Comment: what is num1 and num2 type? it's depends on type of variable too

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `*Classname*.this`